# Would using poll watchers to hold down voter turnout from opposing party in battleground areas be illegal?

Tags: united-states, voting

I have heard something in the news about 50,000 poll watchers being sent by a specific political party that has received fewer votes in most of the presidential elections since 1990 and received almost ten million fewer votes in a House midterm election with historic turnout from its opponents two years ago. I am NOT going to name it because it is more powerful without the name. Let's say that in 2024, this party has lost the midterms. They want to send poll watchers out to heavily populated areas in competitive/battleground states that vote heavily against them in order to swing the Electoral College in their candidate's favor. Would abusing these poll watchers in order to manipulate electoral outcomes be illegal?

Note: I am NOT speculating on anything. This is just a hypothetical. This is a political and legal question about the legality of trying to restrict voting. This does not just involve voter ID laws. It is many things together.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Different states have different laws about poll watchers: who can be one, how many are allowed, what they can do, etc.  See https://www.cnn.com/2016/10/29/politics/poll-watchers-monitors/index.html for an overview.  Are you asking whether a party's plan to get people to be poll watchers would be illegal if its purpose were to suppress opposing votes, even if the individual poll watchers themselves were complying with all relevant state rules?

Comment: I am asking about poll watchers suppressing opposing votes by going to places that oppose them.

Comment: Well, for one thing, many states require that a poll watcher must be registered to vote in the state / county / jurisdiction where they are watching.  So your hypothetical party would have to recruit its poll watchers locally, to some extent; it couldn't take a whole bunch of people from one place and send them out across the country.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MittenFile almost universally, every candidate or party can have poll watchers in every polling place - I therefore don’t understand what you mean by “places that oppose them”.

Comment: Yes that is true. This party has a lot of members but not as many as the opposition and because of this it can recruit them locally.

Comment: I mean "places that oppose them" as places that turn out a lower percentage of votes than surrounding areas.

Comment: What are you thinking of these poll watchers doing that would change the outcome of the vote?

Comment: @bdb484 The whole question seems to be a "I have a scheme whereby I can prevent the dirty unmentionables in party X from winning via voter intimidation in the guise of poll watching; help me figure out where I can legally do this" to me.

Comment: The title question is very different from the body text question: "Would abusing these poll watchers in order to manipulate electoral outcomes be illegal?" I am pretty sure that beating up poll watchers is illegal, but I don't think that this is what you meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

Each state has its own election laws, so you will get 50 different answers depending on what state you are interested in (perhaps 49, since Washington doesn't have polling places - depends on what you mean by "poll watcher"). [This page](https://www.eac.gov/election-officials/poll-watchers) is a starter list of legal resources. [This page](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/policies-for-election-observers.aspx) starts you on deconstructing this notion of "poll watcher". Colorado is one state that explicitly allows partisan observers, [here are the rules](https://www.sos.state.co.us/pubs/rule_making/CurrentRules/8CCR1505-1/Rule8.pdf).

No person is compelled to be an observer, so I don't understand who you think might be abusing a poll watcher. Perhaps you are referring to the possibility that an election official will prevent an observer from doing their job. Or perhaps you are thinking that being a poll watcher abuses the intent of some law. Whatever you have in mind, there are laws in each state that say what is allowed and what is forbidden, so you have to address this at a local level.

No state has a requirement that observers must come from or swear allegiance to the majority party of that polling jurisdiction (e.g. county, or precinct). Any attempt by election officials, or anyone else, to block observers from the minority party would be rebuffed by the courts. The courts will not attempt to divine inner motivations for sending an observer. Most states allow partisan observers. [Michigan](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/SOS_ED_2_CHALLENGERS_77017_7.pdf) distinguishes "challengers" and "poll watchers", and there are distinct rules and powers for the two sets. A crucial difference is that a watcher cannot legally challenge a claimed right to vote or a precinct board action, but a challenger can. There are rules of conduct imposed on both kinds of observers, one of them being that you cannot challenge a voter for the purpose of annoying or delaying the voter. This is a misdemeanor (a crime) under [MCL 168.727](https://www.legislature.mi.gov/documents/mcl/pdf/mcl-168-727.pdf), and as a criminal prohibition, the state would have to prove intent beyond reasonable doubt. Blog posts by the observer might provide sufficient evidence, but speculation by the majority party would not.